# Using a global across multiple source files (using extern multiple times)

Tags: c++, linker

I have a global that I would like to share across multiple files. Lets call it:

library.cpp:

```
HookContext g_context;
```

Then, I have two other files that I wish to access this global in:

A.cpp:

```
extern HookContext g_context;
```

B.cpp;

```
extern HookContext g_context;
```

When I link all these files together, my linker complains with the following warning:

B.obj : error LNK2005: "class HookContext g_context" (?g_context@@3VHookContext@@A) already defined in A.obj

Am I using extern incorrectly? What should I do to access the context in both A and B?

NOTE: In this case, I do not wish to use any header files to define the context.

Thanks

Comment: No, A and B are completely different files defining behavior of completely different classes.

Comment: Answered brilliantly over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

Comment: AFAIK you need to use headers to do it correctly

Comment: Since A and B use exactly the same code... isn't this essentially the same as using #include anyway (aside from maintainability issues)?

Comment: Ravi - I'm currently reading through that large post.. I haven't spotted anything I'm doing wrong yet, is there a specific part of that post that I'm guilty of violating?

Comment: Code as shown is legitimate. If you add `main`, a definition of `HookContext` *and nothing else* to these exact 3 one-line files, compile and link, do you still have an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n.m was correct, the above code in itself is correct.
It turns out one of my lines was actually adding an extra "()" at the end of it. Like this:

extern HookContext g_context();

Which causes g_context to be initialized and instantiated in that translation unit.

When I removed the ()'s it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

I would use some kind of singleton. Gives you the ability to insert some initialization later on or convert it into something else.

library.cpp:

```
static HookContext g_context;
HookContext& getHookContext()
{
  return g_context;
}
```

A.cpp:

```
extern HookContext& getHookContext();
```